# Evaluate an integral in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the following integral:

```
exp(-y^2/(2*a^2))* cosh(y)*log(cosh(y))
```

from `y=0` to `y = Inf`

I need to do this integral for a vector of values `a`? How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute that integral to `y = Inf`? `cosh(1000)` is `Inf` in Matlab and `exp(-1000)` is `0` so you will end up with `NaN` very quickly.

Comment: @IKavanagh: It's okay even if I can compute it numerically upto some upper limit say 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As IKavanagh already noticed, you can not calculate the integral using `integral` because it outruns the range of floating point values. Thus, using the symbolic toolbox is probably the only possibility.

```
%define your function:
syms a y
f=exp(-y^2/(2*a^2))* cosh(y)*log(cosh(y))
```

Now you can calculate the integral:

```
iF=int(f,y,0,inf);
```

At least in my matlab version, an explicit solution could not be found, a warning is raised. Thus we need two steps, substitute a with the intended values, then solve it using `vpa`. In case recent matlab versions find an explicit solution, use of `vpa` is unnessecary.

```
solution=vpa(subs(iF,a,[1,2,3,4]))
```